Jena Apache arq Error: Could not find or load main class arq.arq
On Windows machine. I downloaded the apache-jena-4.9.0.zip. Have tried version 5 as well.
Unzipped and added System Variables as follows:
Variable=JENA_HOME and Value=C:\apache-jena-4.9.0
Variable=Path and Value=C:\apache-jena-4.9.0\bin
In VSC bash terminal I run "arq --version" and get the error
"Error: Could not find or load main class arq.arq".
I need to use bin and not bat to avoid amending scripts by Mac users, but cannot see why this would be an issue.
Not sure if it is important, running Java 20.0.2.
I have tried:

directly on C drive as well as within the users folder.
current version and the one prior.
with bin or bat (interestingly echo $PATH will bring back bat regardless?)
variations of the path
How to solve "Error: Could not find or load main class arq.sparql" when trhing to run the `sparql` CLI tool from Apache Jena?

Not successful.
What am I missing?
There must be a way.

What does "echo $PATH" say? In setting bash PATH (and exporting it) Have backslashes been converted to forward slashes?

Yes actually, they have switched from back slash to forward slash. What does that mean?

It is correct - bash does not use the same directory path separator as windows. Check the PATH in bash is correct, with correct entries, and check JENA_HOME is a correct Linux path.

I was fortunate to receive some advanced help and he found a resolve for the issue as follows:

Edited the arq file located in the Apache Jena bin folder from:
 # Platform specific fixup
 # On CYGWIN convert path and end with a ';' 
 case "$(uname)" in
    CYGWIN*) JENA_CP="$(cygpath -wp "$JENA_CP");";;
 esac



to:
    # Platform specific fixup
    # On CYGWIN convert path and end with a ';' 
    JENA_CP="$(cygpath -wp "$JENA_CP");"


Checked the JAVA_HOME path in the environment variables. Mine was pointing to jdk1.8 instead of the jdk-20. Note: This was corrected first and we still got the same error as posted, but was required to resolve in totality.

I hope this helps someone else or opens for more light to be shed.

For git bash, the uname on Windows 1x is MINGW64_NT*.  Therefore, the case statement should be extended to include this.
CYGWIN*|MINGW64_NT*) JENA_CP="$(cygpath -wp "$JENA_CP");";;

I continue to get an error (ERROR Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for '4e0e2f2a' at 'null' in 'null'), but the query completes with result 0 and the output is correct.
NOTE: This same change will need to be made in the sparql script as well.
